# How to avoid FireFox cutting off vertically centered text due to line-height rounding (Chrome has no issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following requirements:

- Unknown up-front size of content, line-height or even font-size (they can be adjusted by the end-user)
- Text must be vertically centered within the content
- Text must cut off at a certain point with ellipses
- Text must be fully rendered

I've achieved exactly what I want with the following:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kab2twpu/1/)

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

#inner {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

#inner>div {
  display: block;

  padding-right: 25px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div>
      the letter g and y is cut off here in FireFox but not Chrome. this entire div should also
      be vertically centered, but also have its content cut off with ellipses
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly except that in FireFox, the `line-height` of 1.3 results in the lower case characters (such as 'g' and 'y' in this example) being cut off, presumably due to rounding. In Chrome this doesn't happen.

I can of course fix this by removing `overflow: hidden;`, but doing so means I can no longer get the text to ellipse when it's too long.

The other option is to remove the `<div>` entirely and place the content directly in `inner`, however it appears flexbox doesn't support `text-overflow` so that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: make the line-height of the div where you are applying the overflow bigger, instead of inherit

Comment: I think it is related to the font. With other font it works in FF. Increasing the line-height also will work.

Comment: Could give your `#inner > div` a set height. Like `height: 16px;`